# Probability of $A \cup B \cup C$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

the question is this:

a random man draws $1$ card from a deck. let $A$=this card is spade $B$= this card is red $C$= this card is a picture card(so jack,Q,and K)

I need to find $P(A \cup B \cup C)$

so $\frac{13}{52}+\frac{26}{52}+\frac{12}{52}-0-\frac{4}{52}-\frac{3}{52}+0 = \frac{44}{52}$

i got $0.75$ for this (using the formula for $A \cup B \cup C$ ) am i correct? (I edited a bit. My original answer was 39/52)

Comment: Notice possible cards in Union are all spades, hearts, diamonds and king/queen/jack of clubs. A total of 42 cards

Comment: I think you need $P(A\cap C)=\frac{3}{52}$ and $P(B\cap C)=\frac{6}{52}$.  But an alternate method would be to find $P(A'\cap B'\cap C')$

Comment: do I need a U c too? the formula I have for a U b U c is equal to P(a) + p(b) + p(c) - p(a n b) - p(b n c) - p(c n a) + pr(a n b n c). Am I using the wrong formula?

Comment: i think the part I got wring is 4/52 and 3/52. I wrote 4/52 for p(b n c) because I thought among jack,Q and K, Q is the only red cards and there are 4 Q cards. I wrote 3/52 for p(c n a) because there are 3 spades for jack, Q and K. Can anyone tell me where I got wrong?

Comment: No.  I made a typo.  I meant $A\cap C$

Comment: There are a J,Q,K of clubs, J,Q,K of spades, J,Q,K of diamonds, J,Q,K of hearts.  Which are all the color of their suits.  Your value of 3 for the spade picture cards is correct, but for the red picture cards you need 6, not 4.  For the J,Q,K of hearts and J,Q,K of diamonds.

Comment: i see what u mean thank you

Comment: The six cards that are both $B$ (red), and $C$ (a picture card).  They are the J of hearts, Q of hearts, K or hearts, J of diamonds, Q of diamonds, and K of diamonds.  http://whiteknucklecards.com/standards/images/HoylesStandard550.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contend that it is $\frac{42}{52}=\frac{21}{26}$

Using your formula $$\frac{13}{52}+\frac{26}{52}+\frac{12}{52}-\frac{3}{52}-\frac{6}{52}-0+0$$

Answer (score 1):

`possibilities = all spades (13) + all reds (26) + club-KQJ cards (3) = 42.`
`probability = 42 / 52`